# Bootstrap table missing some borders

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a simple table:

[image]

As you can see, It is missing the vertical border that separates columns "Estado" from "Sintoma and "Fecha creación" from "Abrir".

This is the html code corresponding to the table:

```
<table class="table-responsive table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%; margin-top:6px;">
    <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#286090; color:white;">
        <th style="text-align:center;">Tipo</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Número</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Servicio</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Estado</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Síntoma</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Fecha Creación</th>
        <th style="text-align:center;">Abrir</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;" title="INC">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">INC-0003828206</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">GigADSL</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Activo</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">00-No afecta al servicio</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">2017-01-19 14:26</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align:center;">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Abrir enlace</button>
            </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;" title="INC">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px;">INC-0003828206</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px;">IMAGENIO</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Activo</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px;">00-No afecta al servicio</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px;">2017-01-19 14:26</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align:center;">
        <a href="" target="_blank">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Abrir enlace</button>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;" title="INC">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">INC-0003828206</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">VARIOS</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Activo</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">00-No afecta al servicio</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">2017-01-19 14:26</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align:center;">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Abrir enlace</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;" title="INC">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">INC-0003835091</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">GigADSL</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Activo</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">00-No afecta al servicio</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">2017-01-25 10:56</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align:center;">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Abrir enlace</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;" title="INC">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">INC-0003835091</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">IMAGENIO</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Activo</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">00-No afecta al servicio</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">2017-01-25 10:56</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align:center;">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Abrir enlace</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;" title="INC">
            <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">INC-0003835091</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">VARIOS</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">Activo</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">00-No afecta al servicio</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px;">2017-01-25 10:56</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align:center;">
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Abrir enlace</button>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Seems fine to me, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5g2xyc4n/). Or probably there's something on your css that removed the border.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the CSS classes - have a look http://www.bootply.com/PHFYJb7eGC

Comment: Same, I see the vertical borders. Checked on FF and Chrome. Probably you checked it on a zoom out/in page. But if not, can you let me know what browser you're checking it?

Comment: Thanks for your insight guys. @RobinCarloCatacutan I'm using Firefox 50.1 on Linux Mint.